Topological/ (Co)homological Interpretation of Cyclic Covers
I have a question about topological interpretation of concept of cyclic covers as suggested in Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties by Kollár and Mori in Definition 2.49 (p 63):

Let $X$ be a normal variety
(or complex analytic space) and $L$ a line bundle on $X$ such that
$L^m \cong O_X$. The corresponding cyclic cover is a degree $m$
finite etale morphism $p : X_{m,L} \to X$ defined in three equivalent ways:


(1) Topological. $c_1(L) \in H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ is $m$-torsion by assumption, so it
corresponds to a quotient $\pi_1(X) \to H_1(X, \Bbb Z) \to \Bbb Z/m$. (...First map is the Hurewiscz map) [...]

Question: How a $2$-cocycle in $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ is related to such a composition  $\pi_1(X) \to H_1(X, \Bbb Z) \to \Bbb Z/m$. For Poincare-duality the degrees not fit. Any idea?

The idea should be that $c_1(L)$ is, since it is $m$-torsion, in the image of the Bockstein homomorphism $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/m)\rightarrow H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$. However, this homomorphism is not generally injective, so the phrase "corresponds" confuses me here.

@Thorgott: I see, this is maybe just a "vague motivation". And just to clarify, if we additionally assume that Bockstein $b: H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/m)\rightarrow H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is injective and $p^{-1}c_1(L)$ is in the preimage andso  $\Bbb Z/m \cong \langle p^{-1} c_1(L) \rangle \subset H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/m)$, then $ H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/m) \to \Bbb Z/m$ just comes from the canonical duality of cohomology with homology, right? (... especially not Poincare etc)

Yes, the universal coefficient theorem always identifies $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/m)$ with $\mathrm{Hom}(H_1(X;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}/m)$.
